# Singleton Design Pattern Implementation: Bill Pugh

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to implement the Bill Pugh Singleton Design Pattern using a private static class to return the singleton retrofit instance. So far I have been able to come up with the following code. Can someone help me review this code and confirm if this is a proper implementation of the singleton design pattern suggested by Mr. Bill Pugh himself, or suggest a proper way of implementing this?

```
public class SingletonRetrofit {

    private SingletonRetrofit(){}

    private static class SingletonRetrofitHelper
    {   private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
        private static Retrofit retrofit;

        private static Retrofit makeRetrofit()
        {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://ci.draftserver.com/hornsbyapp/webservice/")
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            return retrofit;

        }




    public static Retrofit getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonRetrofitHelper.makeRetrofit();
    }

}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks to me that every time you call *getInstance()* you are going to create a new *Retrofit* instance. And this is not a Singleton I suppose. Instead you should create the instance just the first time. Could you add in your answer a link on the site where you find this approach?

Comment: i tried checking the singleton object to be null and made an instance only if it is null. This works perfectly and i have implemented it in my projects. Then i found this method. 
http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples
Have a read and share insights.

Answer (score 1):

I read the article [Java Singleton Design Pattern Best Practices with Examples](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples), it is an interesting discussion about *Singleton Pattern* and thread safe.

The basic pattern:

```
public class TrivialSingletonTest {
    private static TrivialSingletonTest instance;

    private TrivialSingletonTest() {}

    public static TrivialSingletonTest getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TrivialSingletonTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrivialSingletonTest st1 = getInstance();

        TrivialSingletonTest st2 = getInstance();

        String className = "[" + TrivialSingletonTest.class.getName() + "] ";

        if (st1 == st2) {
            System.out.println(className + "Same object");
        } else {
            System.out.println(className + "Is not a singleton");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic implementation of the *Singleton Pattern* with a *main()* method that test it.

The issue with this implementation is just in a multi threading program, where you could have more than 1 instances.

So the fix proposed:

```
public static synchronized TrivialSingletonTest getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TrivialSingletonTest();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The issue here is just about performances, that's why the proposition of a different approach, using a private static inner class as an helper to obtain the singleton instance.

The main advantages of this solution is that is thread safe without the need of *synchronized*, and that the instance is is created only after the first *getInstance()*, instead of a creation when the class is loaded (thanks to the static stuff).

Now about your code.

As I saw your code is not working.

**First issue**: your class is *SingletonRetrofit* but the object type of your instance is *Retrofit*. So I'm not sure you want to use all the main class as an helper or just a typo.

**Second issue**: you create the instance every time you call *getInstance()* this is not the purpose of a singleton.

Your code should look like:

```
public class SingletonRetrofit {

    private SingletonRetrofit(){}

    private static class SingletonRetrofitHelper
    {   
        private static final SingletonRetrofit INSTANCE = new SingletonRetrofit();
    }

    public static SingletonRetrofit getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonRetrofitHelper.INSTANCE;
    }

    private Retrofit makeRetrofit(final String apiBaseUrl)
    {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

So the *makeRetrofit()* will became a method of the singleton class that you can call in your code to create the *Retrofit* object as needed.

If you want to create this *Retrofit* object just once, and the singleton purpose was this, then you have to design your singleton class in a way that this class cover all the *Retrofit* class interface.